# How to convert a mysql datetime string to c# datetime string?

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I get "`10/1/15 12:00:00 AM"`  time string from mysql db. How to convert this to  a `System.DateTime` by the `ParseExact` method?

Comment: Are you sure that you get it as `String`? And not as already mapped `DateTime`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact) method with a custom date and time format.

I assume your `10` is as a day;

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact("10/1/15 12:00:00 AM", "dd/M/yy hh:mm:ss tt", 
                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

By the way, of course saving your `DateTime` as a `string` in your database is a bad idea. Change your column type to [`DATETIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) data type if you can.

Read: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)